# GUI freezes using Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, frame

I´m new to thread programming  and I started a Thread that moves a JPanel inside a Frame. But when I invoke the method the Frame freezes completely and I have to force it to close.

Here´s the simplified method I´ve implemented

```
public class Thread extends Thread{
    
public void movePanel(Frame f) {
                try {
                    long t = f.getTime();
                    while (true) {
                        f.changeColor();// changes Colour of current JPanel
                        Thread.sleep(t);
                        while (true) {
                            f.setNextPosition(direction);// sets the Position, where the JPanel moves next
                            p = f.getNextPosition();
                            f.moveForward();// moves in given direction
                            Thread.sleep(dauer);
                            if (p == null)// checks if the next Position is accessible {
                                f.moveDown();
                                Thread.sleep(t);
                                while (true) {
                                    f.moveBackwards();
                                    Thread.sleep(t);
                                    if (p == null) {
                                        f.moveDown();
                                        Thread.sleep(t);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
}
```

What could cause the problem?
I would appreciate your help very much.

Comment: Thread.sleep() is blocking the current thread for at least that many miliseconds. The important thing is "blocking"! Look up Thread.wait(t);

Comment: You have a Thread.sleep() and you have a while (true) which never finishes executing so you are continually in a loop. For animation use a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)